# Python handling column levels of dataframe

Tags: python

I am getting out put like:

```
    Job Family  Mean Total Benefits Mean Total Compensation Percent_Total_Benefits
29  Public Service Aide 13650.231154    38340.873187    35.602
33  Park & Zoo  24215.619429    72228.710857    33.526
43  Museum & Cultural Affairs   26548.462000    79514.714000    33.388
```

But I am expecting out column should come like:

```
        Mean Total Benefits Mean Total Compensation Percent_Total_Benefits
Job Family
Public Service Aide 13650.231154           38340.873187            35.602
Park & Zoo          24215.619429           72228.710857            33.526
Museum & Cultural Affairs   26548.462000   79514.714000            33.388
```

The Job Family should come to next level rather than in the same level.
Please provide solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should set this column as the new index:

```
df.set_index("Job Family", inplace=True)
```